# Error getting Scapy to work on Windows: "'module' object has no attribute 'ex_name'"

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10, scapy

I'm trying to run a Python script that involves ARP sniffing and is apparently dependent on the Scapy library being present. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing but I'm reasonably good at Googling, following directions, and copying/pasting. I have it up and running on my Mac, but I'm stuck on what I hope is the last hurdle in getting Scapy working on my Windows computer (which is ultimately the one that needs to be running this script).

I followed all of the instructions at http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows, except that I chose Python 2.7 and used the newer 2.7-compatible versions of everything listed there. I used “python setup.py install” (successfully, as best I could tell) on all installs except Pypcap and Libdnet, which I installed via the Exe as an Administrator as instructed.

Unfortunately, when I type "scapy" into the command prompt to test if it works, I get the following information & error message:

```
C:\scapy-2.3.1>scapy
INFO: Can't import python gnuplot wrapper . Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\\scapy", line 25, in <module>
    interact()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\main.py", line 278, in interact
    scapy_builtins = __import__("all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from arch import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from windows import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 214, in <module>
    ifaces.load_from_dnet()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 173, in load_from_dnet
    self.data[i["name"]] = NetworkInterface(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.update(dnetdict)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 107, in update
    self._update_pcapdata()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 118, in _update_pcapdata
    win_name = pcapdnet.pcap.ex_name(guess)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ex_name'
```

Can anyone help me out? If you need more information please let me know.

I am running Windows 10.

Thanks in advance,
 - Ethan

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

To solve it, i downloaded [dnet-1.12.win32-py2.7.exe](http://dirk-loss.de/scapy/dnet-1.12.win32-py2.7.exe)
and [pcap-1.1.win32-py2.7.exe](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/pypcap/issue-36/comment-0/pcap-1.1.win32-py2.7.exe).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with Scapy's current development version (from the [Github repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy)). Support for Windows has been [updated recently](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1) and should work without the need of Libdnet.

If that's not the case, you should probably [open an issue](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/new).

Answer (score -1):

Try it with scapy3k. Install python3 (e.g. I use Anaconda 3.5), and WinPcap driver. You do not need dnet or pypcap. Install using `pip install scapy-python3` or from http://github.com/phaethon/scapy